# Remove FreeIPA user from computer?

Tags: fedora, freeipa

We connected a computer to our FreeIPA system on the network, no problems there... However, we can't figure out how to remove a FreeIPA user account from the computer after they've logged in at least once.

Were running Fedora 27, and running `userdel -r {username}` results in:

> userdel: cannot remove entry 'admin' from /etc/passwd

we *don't* want to delete the user from FreeIPA, just the system so it no longer shows on the login screen.

** We also tried using gnome's user screen to remove the user, and it prompts to confirm removal, we confirm, but then it doesn't remove the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeIPA does not store users locally, so using 'userdel' will not help.

From your description, it looks like you are interested in removing a user from GDM welcome screen rather than removing a user itself.

GDM uses GNOME AccountsService to store information about recently logged in users. AccountsService stores these details in files `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<username>` and provides a dbus interface to access those details. `UncacheUser` method is what you need:

Running
`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.Accounts /org/freedesktop/Accounts org.freedesktop.Accounts.UncacheUser string:username`

would remove `username` from the list of cached users.